# email file attachment php, Ajax, Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

i have problem with email file attachment php, Ajax, Jquery on the following codes, also i need the file attachment field mandatory. the uploaded file in the form doesn't pass to the email!

i need to place code into the Ajax to receive file(s) from the form and check the empty field, then it everything goes fine pass the fields include file(s) to the form. and from the form to the Email.

HTML Form:

```
<form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="form-label "></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label "></label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMessage" class="form-label "></label>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="inputMessage" placeholder="Phone Example:+1234567890"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>


            <button type="button" class="btn sign-btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">Request</button>

        <p class="statusMsg"></p>
```

my php file :

```
// Submitted form data
$name   = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

/*
 * Send email to admin
 */
$to     = 'info@test.org';
$subject= 'CCI2017 Download Log';

$htmlContent = '
<h4>The CCI 2017 has been downloaded by person, details are given below.</h4>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
        <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone:</th><td>'.$message.'</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

// Set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: ME' . "\r\n";

// Send email
if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
    $status = 'ok';
}else{
    $status = 'err';
}

// Output status
echo $status;die;
```

}

my jquery:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function submitContactForm() {
        var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var regp = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;
        var name = $('#inputName').val();
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
        if (name.trim() == '') {
            alert('Please enter your name.');
            $('#inputName').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.trim() == '') {
            alert('Please enter your email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)) {
            alert('Please enter valid email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (message.trim() != '' && !regp.test(message)) {
            alert('Please enter your Phone.');
            $('#inputMessage').focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit_form.php',
                data: 'contactFrmSubmit=1&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg == 'ok') {
                        $('#inputName').val('');
                        $('#inputEmail').val('');
                        $('#inputMessage').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<a href="Doc/MENACA CCI (c).pdf" class="btn cci-btn-primary btn-sm">Download</a>');
                    } else {
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: _"i need the file attachment field mandatory"_ - What file attachment field? _"the uploaded file in the form doesn't pass to the email"_ - Could it be because it doesn't exist in the form and you're no actually passing it in any way?

Comment: The code to upload files(for email attachments) in missing in your question. Once you have email attachments uploaded, you can use `$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";` to send email with attachment.

Comment: Dear Ahmed, thanks for your reply. i added the file attachment in form field which it missed and also added your commands in php file but problem still exist!

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="form-label "></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label "></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputMessage" class="form-label "></label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="inputMessage" placeholder="Phone Example:+1234567890"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>


<button type="button" class="btn sign-btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">Request</button>

<p class="statusMsg"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function submitContactForm() {
        var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var regp = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;
        var name = $('#inputName').val();
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
        if (name.trim() == '') {
            alert('Please enter your name.');
            $('#inputName').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.trim() == '') {
            alert('Please enter your email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)) {
            alert('Please enter valid email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (message.trim() != '' && !regp.test(message)) {
            alert('Please enter your Phone.');
            $('#inputMessage').focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit_form.php',
                data: 'contactFrmSubmit=1&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg == 'ok') {
                        $('#inputName').val('');
                        $('#inputEmail').val('');
                        $('#inputMessage').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<a href="Doc/MENACA CCI (c).pdf" class="btn cci-btn-primary btn-sm">Download</a>');
                    } else {
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Submit_form.php**

```
<?php

// Submitted form data
$name   = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];


$to = 'kiran.mind2014@gmail.com';

// Subject
$subject = 'CCI2017 Download Log';

// Message
$message = '
<h4>The CCI 2017 has been downloaded by person, details are given below.</h4>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
        <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone:</th><td>'.$message.'</td>
    </tr>
</table>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Kiran <kiran.mind2014@gmail.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: CCI2017 Download Log <kiran.mind2014@gmail.com>';

// Send email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))){
$status = 'ok';
}else{
$status = 'err';
}

// Output status
echo $status;die;
```

It is working fine!!!.

Comment: Dear Kiran, my codes works fine but i want to have file attachment and it didnt work fine, (i know i missed the file upload field in the form). i added the file upload field in the form but problem still exist